# Electron app crash while using external library without any error message

Tags: node.js, electron, node-ios-device

**Description:**

After about 1 week of debugging to figure out the cause of the application closing itself without any error message, I discovered that the main cause of crashing is from the node-ios-device library.
Everything works normally, but after about 1 hour, a crash occurs. What I think is strange is that a crash occurs even `iosDevice.watch()` was not called. Or just by importing the node-ios-devices library can a crash occur.

Sometimes, I got this message after crashing as well.

`[21194:0607/225605.295914:FATAL:message_pump_kqueue.cc(387)] : Bad file descriptor (9)`

It still works on my NodeJS project.

**Reproduction:** 
https://github.com/zcmgyu/crash-electron-node-ios-device/blob/master/main.js#L22-L28

```
const handle = iosDevice.watch();
  handle.on('change', devices => {
    console.log('Connected devices:', devices);
  });
  handle.on('error', console.error);

  iosDevice.on('log', msg => console.log(msg));
```

This is logs output from `iosDevice.on('log')`

```
$ electron .
Creating device list with 1 devices
Connected devices: [
  {
    udid: 'XXXX',
    interfaces: [ 'Wi-Fi' ],
    name: 'ZC X',
    buildVersion: '17F75',
    cpuArchitecture: 'arm64',
    deviceClass: 'iPhone',
    deviceColor: 'Black',
    hardwareModel: 'D22AP',
    modelNumber: 'MQAY2',
    productType: 'iPhone10,3',
    productVersion: '13.5',
    serialNumber: 'FK1VVTGLJCLL',
    trustedHostAttached: false
  }
]
Adding listener
Creating device list with 1 devices
Resetting timer due to new device notification
Device XXXX disconnected via Wi-Fi
Connected devices: []
Creating device list with 0 devices
Dispatching device changes to 1 listener (thread 2978043419396287625)
Resetting timer due to new device notification
Device XXXX connected via Wi-Fi
Getting device info for XXXX
Connecting to device: XXXX
Pairing device: XXXX
Validating device pairing
Starting session: XXXX
Stopping session: XXXX
Disconnecting from device: XXXX
Connected devices: [
  {
    udid: 'XXXX',
    interfaces: [ 'Wi-Fi' ],
    name: 'ZC X',
    buildVersion: '17F75',
    cpuArchitecture: 'arm64',
    deviceClass: 'iPhone',
    deviceColor: 'Black',
    hardwareModel: 'D22AP',
    modelNumber: 'MQAY2',
    productType: 'iPhone10,3',
    productVersion: '13.5',
    serialNumber: 'FK1VVTGLJCLL',
    trustedHostAttached: false
  }
]
Creating device list with 1 devices
Dispatching device changes to 1 listener (thread 2978043419396287625)
Resetting timer due to new device notification
Device XXXX disconnected via Wi-Fi
Connected devices: []
✨  Done in 225.28s.
```

> macOS: 10.15.4
>   node-ios-device: 2.0.2
>   electron: 9.0.2
>   node: 14.3.0

There is no alternative library so I could fulfill my project without this one. Please save my day.